# Can't restart to initial case in finite state machine in case/switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, fsm

I am programming an embedded processor (`Atmega644a`) using `C (Atmel studio)` and I am trying to use this nested case/switch to cycle through my states but when I get to the 3rd state inside my "on" case, it doesn't go back to my `startTrigger` case, even though I set the `current_state` to `startTrigger` inside my rotate function, which I call in my `startRotate` state/case. Also, I am certain that all states are being entered and the functions work for the first cycle through the states. I've posted my code below, this is my first time posting on a forum so I'm not sure if you want the whole thing or not.

**This is my full code**

```
/*
* test_external_interrupts.c
*
* Created: 12/28/2017 10:49:37 AM
* Author : Celeste MacNeil 
*/
//libraries
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "UART_library.h"

// system constants
#define pi 3.14159265359
#define MAX 65535
#define ARRAYmax 11
const float fclk = 14.7456e6;
const float prescale = 1024;
const float cm_meter = 100;
const float speed_of_sound = 343;
const float fclk_echo = 14.7456e6;
const float ten_us = 10e-6;
const float prescale_echo = 8;
const float prescale_speaker = 256;
const float spkr_midpoint = 1.25;

// for input captures
volatile unsigned short current_edge;
volatile float rising_edge_timestamp, falling_edge_timestamp;
volatile float pulse_width;

// for distances
volatile float duration, distance, net_distance;

//counter
int p;

//states
enum fsm {startTrigger, startMeasure,startRotate};
enum fsm current_state;
enum status {on, off};
enum status button_status;

//distance/frequency values arrays and counter
float dist[] = {0,0.363636364,0.727272727,1.090909091,1.454545455,1.818181818,2.181818182,2.5454545,2.909090909,3.272727273,3.636363636,4};
float freq[] = {261.6, 282.7181818, 303.8363636,324.9545455,346.0727273,367.1909091,388.3090909,409.4272727,430.5454545,451.6636364,472.7818182,493.9};

// angle and pulse duration counts/arrays
float angle[] ={-90 ,-75,-60,-45,-30,-15, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90};
float pulseIn[]={0.00054,0.00065,0.0008,0.00094,0.0011,0.00125,0.0014,0.0016,0.0018,0.002,0.0022,0.0023,0.0024};

/******************************************************************************
function to trigger 10us pulse
************************************
******************************************/
void trigger(){
     PORTA |=(1<<PA7);
     /* initialize counter settings */
     TCCR1A = 0;                            // not required since WGM11:0, both are pre-set to zero
     TCCR1B |= (1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS11);        // Mode = CTC, Prescaler = 8
     TIMSK1 |= (1<<OCIE1A)|(1<<ICIE1);                    // set timer to reset when output compare is reached
     TCNT1 = 0;                                // initialize counter
     OCR1A = (int)fclk_echo*ten_us/prescale_echo;        // initialize compare value
    //printf("Trigger\n");
}
/******************************************************************************
When the timer count is reached, do something
******************************************************************************/
ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{   
    PORTA &= ~(1<<PA7);        //end 10us pulse on trigger pin
    TCCR1B |= (1<<ICES1);    //set input capture on rising edge
    TIMSK1 |= (1<<ICIE1);    //set input capture interrupt flag
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12)|(1 << CS11);        // Mode = CTC, Prescaler = 8
    TCNT1 = 0;
    OCR1A = 0;
}
/******************************************************************************
When echo pulse is triggered, capture pulse duration
************************************
******************************************/

ISR (TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    if(current_edge == 1){
        rising_edge_timestamp = ICR1;        //save time stamp
        TCCR1B &= ~(1<<ICES1);    //set input capture on falling edge.
        current_edge = 0;
        }else if(current_edge == 0){
        falling_edge_timestamp  = ICR1;
        TCCR1B |= (1<<ICES1);                   //set input capture to rising edge
        current_edge = 1;
    }

    if(rising_edge_timestamp<falling_edge_timestamp){
        pulse_width = falling_edge_timestamp - rising_edge_timestamp;
        }else{
        pulse_width = MAX - rising_edge_timestamp + falling_edge_timestamp;
    }
    //printf("rising edge: %f\n falling edge :%f\n pulse width: %f\n", rising_edge_timestamp, falling_edge_timestamp,pulse_width);
    _delay_ms(100);
    current_state = startMeasure;
}   
/******************************************************************************
function to sound speaker tones
************************************
******************************************/
void speaker_tones(){
    int q, r=0;
    for(q=0;dist[q]<ARRAYmax;q++){
        while(net_distance>dist[r]*cm_meter){
            r++;
        }
        OCR0A = (int)((fclk_echo/(4*prescale_speaker*freq[r])));
        //printf("%f",freq[r]);
        _delay_ms(3000);
        OCR0A = 0;
    }

}
/******************************************************************************
function to measure echo pulse
************************************
******************************************/
void measure(){
    duration = (pulse_width*prescale_echo)/fclk_echo;
    distance = (duration*speed_of_sound*cm_meter)/2;
    net_distance = sqrt((distance*distance -spkr_midpoint*spkr_midpoint));

    if(distance>spkr_midpoint&&net_distance<395){
        printf("The object distance is %.2f cm away.\n", net_distance);
        printf("The object angle is %.2f degrees.\n\n", angle[p]);
        speaker_tones();
        printf("p in measure is %d\n\n",p);
    }
    _delay_ms(100);
    p++;
    current_state = startRotate;
}
/******************************************************************************
function to rotate servo
*************************************************
*****************************/
void rotate(){
    if(p<=ARRAYmax){
        printf("p in rotate is %d\n\n",p);
        OCR2A = (int)(pulseIn[p]*fclk/prescale); // sets output compare to approx clockcycles per sample
    }else{
        p=0;
        OCR2A = (int)(pulseIn[p]*fclk/prescale); // sets output compare to approx clockcycles per sample
    }
    _delay_ms(100);
    current_state = startTrigger;
}


/******************************************************************************
read the button status on an external interrupt.
*************************************************
*****************************/
ISR (INT2_vect){
    button_status^=button_status|1;
    //printf("%d\n",button_status);
}
    /******************************************************************************
    function to power down or restart cycle
    ************************************
    ******************************************/
void zero_off(){
    p=0;
    OCR2A = (int)(pulseIn[p]*fclk/prescale); // sets output compare to approx clockcycles per sample
}
    /******************************************************************************
    main function:
    ***************************************
    ***************************************/
    int main(void){
        /* initialize output ports */
        DDRB |= (1 << PB3); // Set PB3 (speaker) to write all others unchanged
        DDRA |= (1<< PA7); // set A7 to write, all others are unchanged
        DDRD |= (1<< PD7); // set PD7 to write, all others are unchanged
        PORTB = 0;              
        PORTA = 0;                      

        /*initialize counter settings*/
        TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE0A); // Enable compare interrupt
        TCCR0A |= (1 << COM0A0 | 1 << WGM00);   //pwm phase correct, toggle OC0A
        TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02)|(1 << WGM02); //prescale set to 256
        TCCR2A |= (1<<COM2A1)|(1<<WGM21)|(1<<WGM20);//clear OC2A on compare match fast PWM TOP = 0xFF
        TCCR2B |= (1<<CS22)|(1<<CS21)|(1<<CS20); //set period of PWM to 17.7ms
        TCNT0 = 0;      //set bottom of counter to 0

        /* enable external interrupt button setup */
        EICRA |= (1<<ISC21)|(1<<ISC20);         // set ISC2[1:0] to 0b01, so that the external
                                                // interrupt on PB2 is sensitive to rising edge.
        EIMSK |= (1<<INT2);                     // enable interrupts on PB2

        /*initialize states*/
        button_status = off;
        current_state = startTrigger;
        sei ();     //global interrupt enabled      
        current_edge = 1;           //set rising edge as first ICR timestamp
        init_uart();                //call uart lib

        while (1) // run indefinitely
        {
            switch(button_status){
                case on:
                switch(current_state){
                    case startTrigger:
                    trigger();
                    break;

                    case startMeasure:
                    measure();
                    break;

                    case startRotate:
                    rotate();
                    break;  
                }
                break;

                case off:
                zero_off();
                break;  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is cycling currentState such that it reaches: `startRotate`?

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can see what your code is actually doing

Comment: Normally, each state processing, before exiting, sets a new state.  I don't see any such state changes in the posted code

Comment: I just posted my entire code :)

Comment: since you only call a function in each `case` you might as well make `button_status` and `current_state` into function pointers set into whatever state you are in. at least it would be more readable than 20 lines of nested switch-case-nocode-break. to be honest though I can't find the problem in your code. sorry

Comment: FIRST, we are not interested in your entire code.  What we need is a [mcve].  So all the code specific to your hardware should be removed.

Comment: Regarding lines like: `const float fclk = 14.7456e6;`  this is declaring a `double` literal and then forcing it into a `float`.  Suggest: `const float fclk = 14.7456e6f;`  Note the trailing 'f' that tells the compiler that the value is a 'float' rather than a 'double'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2) consistently indent the code (the 'main' function is indented an additional 4 spaces)   3) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert an appropriate space: around C operators, inside parens, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons

Comment: you might want to re-think this statement: `button_status^=button_status|1;`

Answer (score 0):

I have reduced the code to a minimal size

Notice that the 'problem' switch is only stepped when a certain interrupt occurs, as handled by: `ISR (TIMER1_CAPT_vect)`

The probability is that interrupt is never being triggered.

And now, the shortened code:

```
//#include <avr/io.h>
//#include <avr/interrupt.h>
//#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "UART_library.h"

// note, following statement missing from posted code 
#include <math.h>  // M_PI, sqrt()


//prototypes
void trigger( void );
void measure( void );
void rotate( void );


//states
enum fsm {startTrigger, startMeasure,startRotate};
enum fsm current_state;

int triggered_interrupt;


int main( void )
{
    /*initialize states*/
    current_state = startTrigger;



    while (1) // run indefinitely
    {
        if( triggeredInterrupt )
        {
            triggeredInterrupt = 0;
            puts( "interrupt triggered" );
        }

        switch( current_state )
        {
            case startTrigger:
                puts( "mode: startTrigger" );
                trigger();
                break;

            case startMeasure:
                puts( "mode: startMeasure" );
                measure();
                break;

            case startRotate:
                puts( "mode: startRotate" );
                rotate();
                break;
        } // end switch currentState
    } // end while forever
}


void trigger()
{
    puts( "Trigger" );
}


void ISR (TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    current_state = startMeasure;
}


void measure()
{
    puts( "measure" );
    current_state = startRotate;
}


void rotate()
{
    puts( "rotate" );
    current_state = startTrigger;
}
```